# County-level fixed effect model - how to improve the predictive power

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, residuals

I'm doing a linear regression in the hopes of developing a predictive model for fatal drug overdoses at the county level.  My data looks like this (note, pc=per-capita), there are 504 total observations:

```
County  Year  hispanic_perc  Fentanyl.Crime.Lab.Cases.pc  OpioidHospitalizations.pc  totalSBRArrests.pc  
ADAMS   2014  .3             34.4                         43.3                       5.5 
ADAMS   2015  .6             36.1                         46.3                       1.1  
ADAMS   2016  .4             74.4                         22.6                       3.7 
ADAMS   2017  .3             34.1                         33.6                       3.9 
ADAMS   2018  .3             84.3                         73.3                       3.5 
ADAMS   2019  .5             12.3                         49.2                       1.5 
ADAMS   2020  .3             34.9                         53.6                       9.5 
ADAMS   2021  .6             24.9                         83.1                       3.6 
TOOLE   2014  .7             34.4                         13.9                       3.5 
TOOLE   2015  .8             34.4                         23.0                       7.5  
TOOLE   2016  .7             34.4                         21.1                       3.6 
TOOLE   2017  .6             34.4                         55.7                       3.5 
TOOLE   2018  .7             34.4                         13.8                       8.2 
TOOLE   2019  .3             34.4                         13.9                       3.5 
TOOLE   2020  .9             34.4                         83.1                       9.9 
TOOLE   2021  .1             34.4                         73.8                       3.5
```

For each row, predictors are measured at the current year, and overdose deaths are measured for the following year:

```
County  Year  od.deaths.pc.NxtYr 
ADAMS   2014  6.3            
ADAMS   2015  0.0          
ADAMS   2016  0.0              
ADAMS   2017  4.3             
ADAMS   2018  3.3             
ADAMS   2019  6.6            
ADAMS   2020  4.3            
ADAMS   2021  23.6            
TOOLE   2014  0.0            
TOOLE   2015  7.8              
TOOLE   2016  5.1            
TOOLE   2017  5.6             
TOOLE   2018  0.0             
TOOLE   2019  0.0            
TOOLE   2020  3.9             
TOOLE   2021  0.0
```

**Note that my response variable has many true-zeros!**

Plots of predictors vs `od.deaths.pc.NxtYr` :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My dependent variable `od.deaths.pc.NxtYr` is extremely skewed:

[image]

So, my regression model looks like this (trying to predict next year's overdose death rate, using current year predictor values, plus county as a fixed effect):

```
#This has only the significant variables kept in
linearModSubset <- lmer(od.deaths.pc.NxtYr ~   (1|County) +  
                              hispanic_perc +
                              Fentanyl.Crime.Lab.Cases.pc +
                              opioidHospitalizations.pc +
                              totalSBRArrests.pc
                              ,
                              data=drug.data.county.year.filt)
```

Which gives me:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']

Formula: od.deaths.pc.NxtYr ~ (1 | County) + hispanic_perc + Fentanyl.Crime.Lab.Cases.pc +  
    opioidHospitalizations.pc + totalSBRArrests.pc
   Data: drug.data.county.year.filt

REML criterion at convergence: 3788.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.3239 -0.5651 -0.0974  0.3766  6.1629 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 County   (Intercept) 16.89    4.110   
 Residual             95.21    9.757   
Number of obs: 502, groups:  County, 72

Fixed effects:
                             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                 -1.010451   1.400262  -0.722
hispanic_perc                1.470345   0.234544   6.269
Fentanyl.Crime.Lab.Cases.pc  0.412019   0.046965   8.773
opioidHospitalizations.pc    0.013832   0.002225   6.217
totalSBRArrests.pc           0.013629   0.004174   3.265

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) hspnc_ F.C.L. opdHs.
hispanc_prc -0.484                     
Fntn.C.L.C. -0.132 -0.078              
opdHsptlzt. -0.540 -0.164 -0.001       
ttlSBRArrs. -0.175  0.026 -0.141 -0.237
```

`tab_model` of this same model gives me:

[image]

**Model Diagnostics:**

I plotted `predict(linearModSubset)` vs. `od.deaths.pc.NxtYr` :

[image]

And also did a qqline of residuals:

[image]

**My Questions:**

Seems like this model has some fundamental errors.  Namely, the predictive power of the model decreases drastically with larger values of overdose rate. Could the skewed response variable (also many of my predictors are skewed) be causing this?  When I use a log or sqrt transformation for response variable, many of the correlation coefficients in the model turn to 0.

Currently, two variables are highly significant yet have coefficient of 0, which confuses me..

What is the best metric for judging the predictive power (i.e. accuracy of this model)?

Also, it seems like from bivariate scatterplots there is a relationship between my predictors and response variable, although quite possibly not linear? Should some of my variables be quadratic in the model?

Would love some general feedback in improving this model.. thanks!

Comment: A general comment: your outcome variable is not normal distributed, since it is non-negative. Maybe you should consider a count-data methods, e.g. poisson-regression.

Comment: poisson-regression (i.e. using glm.nb in R) seems to output like only values between 2-3 for predicted per capita value, which is not usable...I don't know why?

Comment: Also, my response variable is non-integer (a per capita rate).  I thought poisson-regression was typically applied when the response variable is integer?

Comment: You're right, for a count data model you would have to transform the data back to overall counts (which might be a possiblity for you). I should have been more clear on that point.